# I've more than 60% of free RAM but i can't run a simple php file

Tags: php, ram

I'm trying to run a simple `.php` file in my local environement :
(Ubuntu 15.10 - Intel® Core™ i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4 - 64-bit - 8GB RAM)

[image: screenshot]

So you are seeing that I've more than 60% of free RAM but I don't why I've always this error :

```
Erreur : Allowed memory size of 4244635648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967674 bytes).
```

I've tried to follow the solution to this similar problem : [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158892/using-only-3-3gb-but-i-have-8gb-ram-even-on-ubuntu-14-04-64bit). But is not resolving my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is something like an endless loop in your php script.

Comment: this can be the case, as the script stops at the end of a second

Comment: If so the only way to get it working is to correct the php script.

Comment: i want to say it can't be, sorry :)

Comment: Could you post php code?

Comment: is not a PHP thing I know. the same code work on another local environment

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a setting that limits how much memory a single script can use.  It doesn't matter how much total RAM your system has if you exceed that value.

If you're running at the console, the file that affects it is likely /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and has a line that reads:

```
memory_limit = XXXXXXX
```

To remove the limit entirely, change it to read:

```
memory_limit = -1
```

However, as others have commented, your script is already trying to use over 4 GB of RAM.  Maybe you should rethink what you're doing or look for bugs in the code that would cause that like some sort of an endless loop.  Most PHP scripts, even CLI scripts, should be using less than 256 MB, for even the hardest tasks.  PHP is not designed for loading in a 2 GB file into memory and working on it in variables, or dumping entire databases into arrays.  Many programmers I've worked with make those kind of mistakes.  Instead put that storage to where it works best - leave it in the DB and work on it line by line, or leave it on the filesystem and do the same.

And if this is a web script and not something you're running at the CLI, you probably don't want to mess with the memory_limit setting, at least not in the neighborhood of 4 GB or more.  That's a bad idea for a web server that serves multiple clients.